# How to get comments within an HTML element by XPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I want to get comments within an HTML element, but apparently, comments are not in the hierarchy of the DOM element.

For example,

```
<!-- FIRST -->
<div id="parent">
<!-- SECOND -->
    <span id="child">
<!-- THIRD -->
    </span
</div>
```

When using the second argument of `$xpath->query` has no effect.

```
$comments=$xpath->query('//comment()');
foreach($comments as $comment){
echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}

// Query (intended) within <div id="parent">
$el = $doc->getElementById('parent');

$comments=$xpath->query('//comment()',$el);
foreach($comments as $comment){
echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}

// Query (intended) within <div id="child">
$el = $doc->getElementById('child');

$comments=$xpath->query('//comment()',$el);
foreach($comments as $comment){
echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

and the outputs of all three loops are the same,

```
 FIRST 
 SECOND 
 THIRD 
 FIRST 
 SECOND 
 THIRD 
 FIRST 
 SECOND 
 THIRD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments have to be selected relative to the given Context node.

The `//` (descendant-or-self) prefix in the xpath expression is selecting every comment anywhere in the node regardless of context.

I suggest to do a relative search using `.//` (self, descendant-or-self) xpath expression to search in the provided context.

For example,

```php
<?php
$xml = <<< XML
<!-- FIRST -->
<div id="parent">
<!-- SECOND -->
    <span id="child">
<!-- THIRD -->
    </span>
</div>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

All comments in the document

```php
<?php
$comments = $xpath->query('.//comment()', $dom);
foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
 FIRST
 SECOND
 THIRD
```

All comments in the `div#parent`

```php
<?php
$el = $dom->getElementById('parent');
$comments = $xpath->query('.//comment()', $el);
foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
 SECOND
 THIRD
```

All comments in `span#child`

```php
<?php
$el = $dom->getElementById('child');
$comments = $xpath->query('.//comment()', $el);
foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
 THIRD
```